# How to Use Google HttpMock in Python?

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm new to Google APIs and currently trying to build some unittest coverage for some of the functionality I've built. Google's [HttpMock](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/mocks) looks perfect for what I want to do, but I can't get the example to work no matter what I do. The full example code copied from Google is:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import HttpMock
import pprint

http = HttpMock('books-discovery.json', {'status': '200'})
api_key = 'your_api_key'
service = build('books', 'v1', http=http, developerKey=api_key)
request = service.volumes().list(source='public', q='android')
http = HttpMock('books-android.json', {'status': '200'})
response = request.execute(http=http)
pprint.pprint(response)
```

I've tried setting `books-discovery.json` to valid json, but still get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testthing.py", line 7, in <module>
    service = build('books', 'v1', http=http, developerKey=api_key)
  File "/Users/Eli/.virtualenvs/BigQueryTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Eli/.virtualenvs/BigQueryTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apiclient/discovery.py", line 207, in build
    developerKey=developerKey, model=model, requestBuilder=requestBuilder)
  File "/Users/Eli/.virtualenvs/BigQueryTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Eli/.virtualenvs/BigQueryTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apiclient/discovery.py", line 249, in build_from_document
    base = urlparse.urljoin(service['rootUrl'], service['servicePath'])
KeyError: 'rootUrl'
```

What am I doing wrong? Does `books-discovery.json` need to have some special form not mentioned anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

books-discovery.json needs to be the discovery service file to build the books API and a saved response

see the note from the docs

> As you develop and test your application, it is a good idea to save
>   actual API responses in files like books-discovery.json or
>   books-android.json for use in testing.

Here is **books-discovery.json**

> https://gist.github.com/Bachmann1234/19fddfb983022218204a

and here is **books-android.json**

> https://gist.github.com/Bachmann1234/a2b4207caa29dbc23e29

With these two files the sample runs

So what you are doing is saying "Rather than make this HTTP call just return this content and status"

You still need to provide the appropriate content so the code can function. You just don't need to rely on the HTTP call to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes looking for the answer, here it is, from [my comment on the Github issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/issues/208):

> The problem seems to be that `build()` will use the provided `http` object
>   to fetch the discovery doc even when using `HttpMock`. With caching
>   disabled, or when you don't have a cached version of the document (in
>   my case it was on Travis CI, but not on my local machine), this will
>   cause it to fail -- a nondeterministic failure depending on the state
>   of your cache, which is awesome.
>
> To reproduce:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
>
> from apiclient.discovery import build
> from apiclient.http import HttpMockSequence
>
> http = HttpMockSequence([({'status': '200'}, "{}")])
> build('calendar', 'v3', cache_discovery=False, http=http)
> ```
>
> Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reproduce-bug.py", line 7, in <module>
    build('calendar', 'v3', cache_discovery=False, http=http)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py",line
    credentials=credentials)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 318, in build_from_document
    base = urljoin(service['rootUrl'], service['servicePath'])
KeyError: 'rootUrl'
```

> After tearing my hair out, I've discovered a workaround: **simply call
>   `build('calendar', 'v3')` (or, in your case, `build('books', 'v1')`) with no other arguments before using mocking
>   and it will work fine.**

Comment: How do you get the calendar discovery json? As described here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/mocks